# Azure SQL Database download .bacpac

Tags: database, azure, blob, storage, bacpac

I want to export my current database backups from Azure to my local on-premise environment.  I have created a .bacpac file from the Azure SQL Database and stored this within my Azure Blob Storage.

However, whenever I download my backup it is always downloaded as a .ZIP file and not a .bacpac file.  How can I ensure that I download a .bacpac file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are prompted to save the file locally, simply change the extension from .ZIP to .bacpac.

A [.bacpac file is simply a ZIP file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) (with a .bacpac extension and contains the metadata and data from the SQL Server database).

Comment: I did this and tried to restore it on local SQL server and it does not work.
Maybe on Azure SQL will work? 
Thanks

Comment: I think I need more detail because we seem to be gaining more detail as each response is posted.  Can you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To export your [SQL Database from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export), navigate to the Azure portal for your SQL Database.  You should be able to simply click the 'export' button at the top of the 'Overview' blade.

[image: Azure SQL Database Overview Blade]

On the next blade, you will then need to specify

- The BACPAC filename
- The Azure storage account
- The container for export, and
- The credentials to connect to the source database

You can then see the progres under "Import/Export" history on the 'Overview' blade towards the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, but I already did this. My question is why when the bacpac is exported to the blob storage I can download only the .zip file but not .bacpac file?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  Are you asking how to create a .bacpac when exporting an Azure SQL Database or one or more (all?) blobs from Azure storage?  That is, are you trying to export all your blobs from Azure storage?

Comment: I want to be able to restore the .bacpac after I delete it from my storage account. So is it possible to download .bacpac from azure blob storage? Or I can download only .zip?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still confused.  Have you created a .bacpac and stored it within your Blob storage, and now you are trying to export that item?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But when I download it to my local PC the format is .zip not .bacpac. How can I download .bacpac format?